# Paypal Receipt by Transaction ID

Tags: paypal

Is there is a way to to show Payment Receipt from paypal by transaction id. Is there is a way to show the receipt i already search but unable to find a good solution.

Answer (score 0):

It's unclear what you mean by "receipt", but basically no. Use the response you receive from PayPal to show your own order confirmation.